# .Q.chk gives a "type" error when ran on a hdb. how can I debug or what should I check?

Tags: kdb

.Q.chk gives a type error when ran on one of our hdb .

any ideas what can cause that ?

the same hdb format works on a different host .

Answer (score 3):

If `.Q.chk` errors, and it isn't the "no such file or directory" error mentioned in the documentation (https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qchk-fill-hdb), then your database is in some sort of broken state which could be for any number of reasons (mix of data written in kdb version <3.6 and data written using >=3.6, or mix of data written in kdb version <3.0 and data written >=3.0, it could be a corrupt file somewhere, a date folder inside a date folder...the list is too big).

Your options are:

1. Inspect the k code underpinning `.Q.chk` and run the k code (or convert it to q code and run it) line by line to see where the problem is.
2. This topic came up on the k4 listbox/topicbox back in 2017.08.22. Some good suggestions there were:

   a. Query `select from table where i=0` for each partitioned table in the database to see which one gives an error and why. This query is deliberately inefficient as it scans each partition but that's the point - it should help find a bad partition.

   b. On linux, run q in `strace` before kicking off `.Q.chk`, you might get some info there.

   c. Make sure you don't have any date directories inside the date directories. You could write a shell command or q command to scan for this
3. I had written this "selective" .Q.chk function many years ago which would allow you to run `.Q.chk` one table at a time - this could help you narrow down the issue to a particular table.

```
k).Q.chk2:{f:{`/:'x,'d@&(d:!x)like"[0-9]*"};d@:>.:'$last'`\:'d:$[`par.txt in!x;,/f'-1!'`$0:`/:x,`par.txt;f x]
{[e;u;d]u[i]{.[x;(y;`);:;?[z;();0b;()]]}[d]'e i:&~u in!d}[d[(+u in/:t)?\:1b](0#.)'u,'`;u:.q.inter[(),y;?,/t:!:'d]]'d};

.Q.chk2[`:.;`table1`table2];
```

**However** please note that I haven't used or tested that function in years so use it at your own peril. Test it somewhere else first maybe.